Laravel Carbon (How to calculate exit next payment date)
I need to get  exit next date of payment of loan:
as loan date:    1-1-2020
loan period:   2 years 5 months
payment date:   ? ?
calculating expected date of payment
// calculating next payment date
 date("Y-M-D", strtotime(date("2020-1-1")." + 2 years  + 2 months"))


you could simply do using Carbon like this: Carbon::create(2020, 1, 1)->addYears(2)->addMonths(5)

Try this,
// Loan start date
$loanStartDate = new DateTime("2020-01-01");

// Loan period: 2 years and 5 months
$loanPeriod = new DateInterval("P2Y5M");

// Add the loan period to the loan start date
$nextPaymentDate = clone $loanStartDate;
$nextPaymentDate->add($loanPeriod);

// Output the next payment date
echo $nextPaymentDate->format("Y-m-d");

IT will output the date that is 2 years and 5 months after January 1, 2020. In this case, it would output 2022-06-01.
DateInterval Format Components
P - Starts the period
Date Components
Y - Years (e.g., 2Y for 2 years)
M - Months (e.g., 5M for 5 months)
D - Days (e.g., 10D for 10 days)

nice ChatGPT copy paste answer :)

$loanPeriod = new DateInterval("P2Y5M");
how i could pass dynamically data in DateInterval like "P $y Y $m M"

DateInterval receives a string, so just concatenate the values you want following the format.
$loanPeriod = new DateInterval("P" . $years . "Y" . $months . "M");

Try this, your code is correct and the date format is incorrect:
date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("2020-1-1")." + 2 years  + 2 months"))

OR
date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("2020-1-1")." + 2 years  + 2 months"))


It is better to use Carbon Library, so I would first make the date a Carbon instance.
$date = Carbon::make('1-1-2020');

$paymentDate = $date->addYears(2)->addMonths(5);

Also, if you need specific formatting for the date, use
format(); in your case
$paymentDate->format('d-m-Y');
so the output would look something like: "01-06-2022"
